# Draw border around bitmap

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, compact-framework

I have got a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` in my code.

The width is fix, the height varies.

What I want to do, is to add a white border around the bitmap, with about 20 pixel, to all 4 edges.

How would this work?

Comment: I thought about creating a graphics object with the width +40 px and height +40 px of the bitmap  (20 for each side). I set white background and add the bitmap in the middle, but I can't really figure out how to do...

Comment: And... you tried that? Or at least started to code something toward that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could draw a rectangle behind the bitmap. The width of the rectangle would be (Bitmap.Width + BorderWidth * 2), and the position would be (Bitmap.Position - new Point(BorderWidth, BorderWidth)). Or at least that's the way I'd go about it.

EDIT:
Here is some actual source code explaining how to implement it (if you were to have a dedicated method to draw an image):

```
private void DrawBitmapWithBorder(Bitmap bmp, Point pos, Graphics g) {
    const int borderSize = 20;

    using (Brush border = new SolidBrush(Color.White /* Change it to whichever color you want. */)) {
        g.FillRectangle(border, pos.X - borderSize, pos.Y - borderSize, 
            bmp.Width + borderSize, bmp.Height + borderSize);
    }

    g.DrawImage(bmp, pos);
}
```

Comment: +1. That's the way I'd do it, but the OP might need some code to cinch the answer.

Answer (score 9):

You can use 'SetPixel' method of a Bitmap class, to set nesessary pixels with the color. But more convenient is to use ['Graphics'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) class, as shown below:

```
bmp = new Bitmap(FileName);
//bmp = new Bitmap(bmp, new System.Drawing.Size(40, 40));

System.Drawing.Graphics gr = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

gr.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.White, 20), new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 40));
gr.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.White, 20), new Point(0, 0), new Point(40, 0));
gr.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.White, 20), new Point(0, 40), new Point(40, 40));
gr.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.White, 20), new Point(40, 0), new Point(40, 40));
```

Comment: This method is destructive to the bitmap however, and only works for inset borders (although I'll grant it, my method only works for outset borders).

Answer (score 7):

Below function will add border around the bitmap image. Original image will increase in size by the width of border.

```
private static Bitmap DrawBitmapWithBorder(Bitmap bmp, int borderSize = 10)
{
    int newWidth = bmp.Width + (borderSize * 2);
    int newHeight = bmp.Height + (borderSize * 2);

    Image newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
    using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
    {
        using (Brush border = new SolidBrush(Color.White))
        {
            gfx.FillRectangle(border, 0, 0,
                newWidth, newHeight);
        }
        gfx.DrawImage(bmp, new Rectangle(borderSize, borderSize, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));

    }
    return (Bitmap)newImage;
}
```